# how to link part of a table with a link?

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table with many td's inside a li. the first td is a checkbox , so I want to link all td's with a link excluding the td of the checkbox like the following:

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <table>
            <tr>
               <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
               <a href="#">
               <td>
                 name1
               </td>
               <td>
                  name2
               </td>
               </a>
            </tr>
     </table>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried this but it is not working is it possible to do it like this or I am doing it wrong?

Comment: this is wrong markup, `a` can't be inside a `tr`.

Comment: Is there any way to make those td's as one link?

Comment: you can either use only one `td` with `Div` inside or link the event on both `tds` using css `class`.

Comment: can I use it with the name attribute not with class?

Comment: Consider a different approach that does not split the name into two cells. Note that for accessibility and usability, there should be `label` element for the checkbox, and it should contain the complete name. If the parts of the name should be tabulated, consider setting a width (in `em` or `ch` units) on the first name (which you would wrap in a `span`). It’s not flexible, but might be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

`<td><a href="#">name1 &nbsp name2</a></td>`

Comment: can u elaborate ur question..??

Answer (score 0):

May be try this.. hope it may serve ur purpose..

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <a href="#"> name1 name2 </a>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello friend, what exactly are u in need of? if u could elaborate then it would be better for me to understand?

Answer (score 0):

Well, a very dirty solution is make an anchor with `position:absolute;` that cover the entire tr (except the first one). Something like this:

```
<td>
  <a class="link" href="#"></a>
  name1
</td>

a.link {
    background:transparent; 
    width:70%; /* I set this width because it fits aproximately with the `<tr>`excluding the first `<td>` */ 
    position:absolute;  /*The magic */
    height:1em;
}
```

But... it's a dirty solution. I'm not sure if it helps, anyhow, [here's the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yug3F/) ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try,

```
<td>
    <a href="#">
             name1
  </td>
           <td>
              name2
   </a>
   </td>
```